# Is it possible to add a library to the import section of a linux binary?

Tags: c++, linux, dll, dllimport, code-injection

Background info:
On windows I have a custom patcher on a dll that I use to change code inside a process (I have included this dll to its import table, so I don't really need to inject it at runtime).

The patcher is rather robust and I use it to do several things:

- Write jumps/calls to my own functions
- Overwrite specific process memory offset
- Assign memory to variables/structs/etc

I would like to know if it's possible to add a library to the import section of a binary on linux.
Failing that, what would be the best approach to do something similar to the above? I read about LD_PRELOAD but I'm not sure if that can be used the way I need to, since it seems to just override functions in shared libraries.

OBS: The binaries I want to modify are compiled statically, so I also don't have dynamic symbols, ldd returns nothing.

EDIT: So, after a long time searching online and reading documentation and trial/error testing of stuff, I decided the easiest way to do it was:

- Create a custom launcher that [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)'s itself, and run the binary inside itself using [execl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)
- Before even letting the program run, use [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)'s poke/peek to write/read the desired memory values (I recommend reading [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6210), there is some very useful information and the putdata/getdata methods there are a good base for a patching system)
- You can keep the launcher running within an infinite loop, but I had to use PTRACE_DETACH instead of just PTRACE_CONT after I made my changes, so in case you run into problems with the child process, try that.

Comment: Isn't what you're looking to do the source of most viruses under Windows? I'm not saying the technique doesn't have its legitimate uses too, but injecting code into a process not designed for it is asking for trouble! I don't think Linux allows what you're asking to do, but I'm sure if it does, someone will post an answer rather than a comment like I have. The closest I know you might do (not easily, and that's an understatement) would be to modify the entry point to point to new code which you also add inside the executable... not just a library reference.

Comment: This has nothing to do with viruses in my case, I'm a reverse engineer and use this to write new functionality to software I like but can't otherwise modify, keep in mind those modifications on my end are also personal, and therefore, are not impacting anyone but me.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you were up to anything malevolent; I apologize if it sounded this way. You might be interested in researching the `ptrace()` function (which is the basis for writing debuggers). http://pramode.net/articles/lfy/ptrace/pramode.html is a useful starting point. ptrace() doesn't do what you're asking for, it's much lower level. With it, you could probably figure out how to launch a process and then convince it to run some arbitrary code. Be aware that while actively being traced, the child's performance will suffer.

Comment: Hmm I see, though it seems to be a bit different from what I wanted to do, which is basically modify the process memory, redirecting calls/changing memory/etc before it runs, while keeping my library on it's memory in order for the call redirections to work.

Comment: ptrace allows you to modify process memory, redirect system calls, even inject code to load a library. Google "ptrace tricks" and you'll come up with a trove of information on the first few pages.

Comment: Yeah, what I think I'll have to do, although I still need to test to see if it will work, is load the binary though a custom launcher, and use ptrace on it before it runs to inject the code, it wouldn't be a library anymore, but a launcher though, and I'm not sure if the binary will be able to access the functions inside my launcher which are going to be redirected, since they would technically be in different processes. I'll give that a shot, thanks.